# Loop over Collection of Collections

Tags: vba

I have a collection of collections. The inner collections hold string items.

Filling inner Collection:

```
Function collect_excellent_Companies(ByVal folderName As String, ByVal fileName As String) As Collection
..
    Do While .Cells(countGreens, 1).Interior.Color = 65280
        myCol.Add CStr(.Cells(countGreens, 4).Value2)
        countGreens = countGreens + 1
    Loop
...
End Function
```

Filling the outer Collection:

```
For iRow = 1 To LastRow
     param1 = .Cells(iRow, 1).Value2 + "-Info"
     param2 = .Cells(iRow, 1).Value2
     fullCollection.Add collect_excellent_Companies(param1, param2)
Next iRow
```

Now I want to loop over the outer and inner collections with

```
Dim sepCol As Collection
Set sepCol = New Collection
Dim tmpCol As Collection
Set tmpCol = New Collection
Dim myStr As Object
'Loop over each competion
For Each sepCol In myCol
    For Each myStr In sepCol
            tmpCol.Add myStr
    Next myStr
next sepCol
```

I have checked the content of the collection before this loop and it is everything ok. The error I get is in the line:

```
For each myStr in sepCol
```

`Runtime Error 424: Object necessary.` I already changed `Dim myStr as String` to D`im myStr as Object` but this does not help. Any idea who I get this working would be very welcome!

Comment: You need to loop each ITEM in the collection, you're saying for each collection in my collection, which is logical, but what ever it is, it is an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

I had to set

```
Dim myStr as Variant
```

Comment: There is a fixed period of time where you cannot accept your own answer! I think it is two days or so.